# How can I decoding CloudFront signed URLs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, amazon-cloudfront

I want decode this original link:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
_atrk_opts = { atrk_acct:"Q0s3k1a0CM00EJ", domain:"rtopi.com",dynamic: true};
(function() { 
    var as = document.createElement("script"); 
    as.type = "text/javascript"; as.async = true; as.src = "https://d31qbv1cthcecs.cloudfront.net/atrk.js"; 
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(as, s); 
})();
</script>
<noscript><img src="https://d5nxst8fruw4z.cloudfront.net/atrk.gif?account=Q0s3k1a0CM00EJ" style="display:none" height="1" width="1" alt="rtopi.com" /></noscript>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "decode"?

Comment: why he using this ? what is inside this link ? so ...

Comment: The ? starts the URL's query string. The query string for this URL is the account number, hence `account=Q0s3k1a0CM00EJ`